# Using preg_replace() for suffix and postfix amid other text

Tags: php, regex, text, replace

I've been trying to make a mini markup parser similar to Markdown in PHP. The input looks like this:

> Some text **that is bold!** and some other text

into

> Some text <b>that is bold!</b> and some other text

I've found countless resources on how to replace a chunk of text with another, but only one that actually replaces suffix and postfix: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917064/2194007). After messing around with it a bit it looks like this:

```
$s=preg_quote("**");

$in = preg_replace(
    array('%'.$s.'-%', '%-%', '%'.$s.'%'), 
    array('<b>','_','</b>'),
    $in);
```

Earlier attempts are equally clumsy. It's obvious I don't really get regex or that engine's syntax so I'm at a loss. The alternative is to hack the string into pieces and add/remove what I need, but regex seems much more elegant. Any ideas?

---

Fix: Earlier I wrote `$s=preg_quote($s)` by mistake, corrected to `$s=preg_quote("**")`

Comment: Hm ... it wont work if the bold asterisks are at the end or the start of the string, but maybe it inspires somebody to use that expressions to replace: `\s\*{2}` and  `\*{2}\s` or just the full expression :D `\*\*(.*?)\*\*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a basic '\*\*(.+?)\*\*' regex.

```
$s = preg_replace(
    '/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/isU',
    '<b>$1</b>',
    $s);
```

Comment: Single backslashes are enough in php and you should use non greedy `.+?`.

Comment: OK, it deserves +1 then.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with php pre_replace and its way to accept arrays like you show in your code. But generally speaking a regex approach to this would look like this:

Search for `\*\*(.*?)\*\*` and replace with `<b>\1</b>`. Let me explain this:

We are looking for a string in the form `**any text here**` the `*` need to be escaped because they have a special meaning in regex - hence the `\*`. The central part of the regex `(.*?)` is matching any string (`.` matches any character) of arbitrary length (`*` here has its regex meaning). But we only want to look for the next `**` (there might be more later in the string) so we have to search *ungreedy* (hence the `?`). The brackets makes the regex engine capture whatever is matched by this part of the regex.

Finally we reference the matched part by using `\1` (also `$1` is possible in some engines).

Comment: You might have to add regex delimiters to the search string in php: `/`.

Comment: `\1` is reserved for the regex part. You have to use `$1` in thye replacement part.

Comment: Upvoted for explanation but accepted Nicolas' for simplicity. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$string = explode('**', $sometext);
$newstr = '';
$size = count($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i)  {
    if (($i % 2 == 0 || $i == 0 )&& $i != $size-1 )
        $newstr .= $string[$i]."<b>";
    else if($i % 2 != 0 && $i != $size && $i != $size-1 )
        $newstr .= $string[$i]."</b>" ;
    else if($i == $size-1)
        $newstr .= $string[$i];
}

echo $newstr;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/phVNr)

Comment: Yes that's the alternative method I had in mind. Too much room for error I'm afraid, I'd really rather have the regex.

Comment: There would've been room for error if I had written it myself so that wasn't accurate. I'd rather not go with this because of code size; 7 lines instead of the 1-liner a regex offers. Thanks though

Comment: check this link http://3v4l.org/GB7eO   if there is `****` then regex will not give <b></b>. Also regex will not work even if you have `**` at the end. If you dont want to cover those scenarios you can use regex which is very simple